# How to let Robocopy remove extra file first

Tags: windows-10, robocopy

I use

```
Robocopy src dst /MIR /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS
```

to backup src. It says target hard drive doesn't have enough space during the process. The target indeed have enough space, since a lot of files in src have been removed.

How to set the flags to let ROBOCOPY remove extra files first to release space, then copy new/updated files?

Comment: You could try to run `/purge` maybe with `/nocopy` upfront. In theory that's included with `/MIR`.

Comment: @Seth The reason seems to be that if there are folders that only exist in dst. /purge doesn't work. First append /nocopy to the command solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noted robocopy is probably trying to crawl your tree and apply the necessary changes. This includes copying new files. It doesn't first remove old content because it would mean it has to crawl the tree twice. This might be pretty slow depending on the underlying filesystem.

In theory `/mir` does what you want. It's a combination of `/purge` and `/e`. But as your destination is already full you want the removal operations to happen before anything new is copied. To do this you should be able to use `/nocopy`. You might need to run this independently with `/purge`.

[Robocopy help](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy):

> - /e  Copies subdirectories. Note that this option includes empty directories. For additional information, see Remarks.
> - /purge  Deletes destination files and directories that no longer exist in the source. For additional information, see Remarks.
> - /mir    Mirrors a directory tree (equivalent to /e plus /purge). For additional information, see Remarks.
> - /nocopy     Copies no file information (useful with /purge).

Comment: /mir with /nocopy worked well!